# Unit tests fail in CircleCI with org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, continuous-integration, circleci

I am struggling with our circle CI server. More specifically the unit tests
fail. In my `circle.yml` file I call

```
build:
working_directory: ~/code
docker:
  - image: circleci/android:api-25-alpha
environment:
  _JAVA_OPTIONS: "-Xmx3072m"
  GRADLE_OPTS: '-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-Xmx3072m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"'
# Only run build if on master or develop branch
branches:
  only:
    - master
    - develop
steps:
  - checkout
  - run:
      name: Compile Debug
      command: ./gradlew app:assembleDebug
  - run:
      name: run tests
      command: |
        ./gradlew testDebugUnitTest --debug
```

On my machine (mac OS) the the tests run fine (testDebugUnitTest), but
on circle this is what I get:

```
11:32:07.045 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
11:32:07.045 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
11:32:07.046 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
11:32:07.046 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
11:32:07.046 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:testDebugUnitTest'.
11:32:07.046 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Process 'Gradle Test Executor 3' finished with non-zero exit value 137
11:32:07.046 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
11:32:07.046 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
11:32:07.046 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.  Run with --scan to get full insights.
11:32:07.046 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
11:32:07.046 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
11:32:07.046 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger]
11:32:07.046 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 47s
11:32:07.046 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 30 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 28 up-to-date
11:32:07.047 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService] Worker lease root.1 completed (0 worker(s) in use)
11:32:07.047 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker Thread 3: released lock on root.1
11:32:07.047 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Run build'
11:32:07.050 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for file content cache (/home/circleci/code/.gradle/4.4/fileContent)
11:32:07.051 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on file content cache (/home/circleci/code/.gradle/4.4/fileContent).
11:32:07.053 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for Build Output Cleanup Cache (/home/circleci/code/.gradle/buildOutputCleanup)
11:32:07.053 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on Build Output Cleanup Cache (/home/circleci/code/.gradle/buildOutputCleanup).
11:32:07.056 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for task history cache (/home/circleci/code/.gradle/4.4/taskHistory)
11:32:07.056 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on task history cache (/home/circleci/code/.gradle/4.4/taskHistory).
11:32:07.061 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 0 (avg: 0.0 secs, total: 0.0 secs)
11:32:07.061 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 0 (avg: 0.0 secs, total: 0.0 secs)
11:32:07.061 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.ResolutionResultsStoreFactory] Deleted 4 resolution results binary files in 0.0 secs
11:32:07.064 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.deployment.internal.DefaultDeploymentRegistry] Stopping 0 deployment handles
11:32:07.064 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.deployment.internal.DefaultDeploymentRegistry] Stopped deployment handles
11:32:07.064 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for Artifact transforms cache (/home/circleci/.gradle/caches/transforms-1)
11:32:07.065 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on Artifact transforms cache (/home/circleci/.gradle/caches/transforms-1).
11:32:07.073 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Cache Generated Gradle JARs cache (/home/circleci/.gradle/caches/4.4/generated-gradle-jars) was closed 0 times.
11:32:07.073 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for file hash cache (/home/circleci/code/.gradle/4.4/fileHashes)
11:32:07.074 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache fileHashes.bin (/home/circleci/code/.gradle/4.4/fileHashes/fileHashes.bin)
11:32:07.074 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on file hash cache (/home/circleci/code/.gradle/4.4/fileHashes).
11:32:07.075 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for artifact cache (/home/circleci/.gradle/caches/modules-2)
11:32:07.079 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache module-artifact.bin (/home/circleci/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.36/module-artifact.bin)
11:32:07.079 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache module-artifacts.bin (/home/circleci/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.36/module-artifacts.bin)
11:32:07.079 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache module-metadata.bin (/home/circleci/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.36/module-metadata.bin)
11:32:07.079 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache module-versions.bin (/home/circleci/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.36/module-versions.bin)
11:32:07.079 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on artifact cache (/home/circleci/.gradle/caches/modules-2).
11:32:07.079 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild] The daemon has finished executing the build.
11:32:07.232 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientInputForwarder] Dispatching close input message: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.CloseInput@eaa94e1
11:32:07.232 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 25: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.CloseInput
11:32:07.235 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient] Received result Failure[value=org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:testDebugUnitTest'.] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=2823, address=[f8485678-e447-42bd-80eb-9d84a6e9403f port:39481, addresses:[/127.0.0.1]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1532518089200, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=837b7cd4-a87f-4f8d-8a2c-eca62f271767,javaHome=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64,daemonRegistryDir=/home/circleci/.gradle/daemon,pid=2823,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx3072m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]} (build should be done).
11:32:07.235 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Finished
```

Here is also the stacktrace that was ouput:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:testDeDebugUnitTest'.
> Process 'Gradle Test Executor 4' finished with non-zero exit value 137

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:testDeDebugUnitTest'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:59)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:128)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:314)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:204)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:134)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:109)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'Gradle Test Executor 4' finished with non-zero exit value 137
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:382)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.DefaultWorkerProcess.waitForStop(DefaultWorkerProcess.java:190)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.DefaultWorkerProcessBuilder$MemoryRequestingWorkerProcess.waitForStop(DefaultWorkerProcessBuilder.java:228)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.ForkingTestClassProcessor.stop(ForkingTestClassProcessor.java:122)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.processors.RestartEveryNTestClassProcessor.endBatch(RestartEveryNTestClassProcessor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.processors.RestartEveryNTestClassProcessor.stop(RestartEveryNTestClassProcessor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.FailureHandlingDispatch.dispatch(FailureHandlingDispatch.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.dispatchMessages(AsyncDispatch.java:133)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.access$000(AsyncDispatch.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch$1.run(AsyncDispatch.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.BuildOperationIdentifierPreservingRunnable.run(BuildOperationIdentifierPreservingRunnable.java:39)
        ... 3 more
```

I googled to figure out a solution. I found that in our code there were some
errors, but for Android Studio they were not fatal enough. 
**Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?**

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured this out. I checked `dmesg` and the docker container in CircleCI, which runs ubuntu killed the java process. Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38967991/why-are-my-gradle-builds-dying-with-exit-code-137#39705290) helped me to start the gradle tasks with `--no-daemon`.
Now the all tests run smoothly. :)

**EDIT:** the above approach does not always work, since we have to run tests and builds for two different flavors, which is very memory consuming. We finally solved it by following [this guide](https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/115014359648-Exit-code-137-Out-of-memory) and letting our builds run with more RAM.