# CircleCI ./gradlew test command fails

Tags: android, gradle, android-testing, robolectric, circleci

The gradlew test commands fails on CircleCI. 
When I execute the same command locally it works fine and all the test cases are passed. 
I am attaching yml file, logs from CircleCI and my test class.

Here is my yml file.

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/code
    docker:
    - image: circleci/android:api-28
    environment:
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx4096m
      CC_TEST_REPORTER_ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    steps:
    - checkout
    - restore_cache:
        key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}
    #      - run:
    #         name: Chmod permissions #if permission for Gradlew Dependencies fail, use this.
    #         command: sudo chmod +x ./gradlew
    - run:
        name: Download Dependencies
        command: ./gradlew androidDependencies
    - save_cache:
        paths:
        - ~/.gradle
        key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}
#    - run:
#        name: Run Lint Tests
#        command: ./gradlew lint test
    - run:
        name: Run Tests
        command: ./gradlew test --info

#    - run:
#        name: Run Instrument Tests
#        command: ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest

    - store_artifacts: # for display in Artifacts: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/artifacts/
        path: app/build/reports
        destination: reports
    - store_test_results: # for display in Test Summary: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/collect-test-data/
        path: app/build/test-results
```

When I check the logs for CircleCI, these are the logs :

> > Executing transform IdentityTransform -> IdentityTransform on artifact
> >     core.jar (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0) Executing transform
> >     IdentityTransform -> IdentityTransform on artifact protobuf-java.jar
> >     (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.6.1) Executing transform
> >     IdentityTransform -> IdentityTransform on artifact
> >     backport-util-concurrent.jar
> >     (backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:3.1) Executing
> >     transform IdentityTransform -> IdentityTransform on artifact
> >     xercesMinimal.jar (nekohtml:xercesMinimal:1.9.6.2) Executing transform
> >     IdentityTransform -> IdentityTransform on artifact nekohtml.jar
> >     (nekohtml:nekohtml:1.9.6.2) Executing transform MockableJarTransform
> >     on file /opt/android/sdk/platforms/android-28/android.jar Starting
> >     process 'Gradle Test Executor 2'. Working directory:
> >     /home/circleci/code/app Command:
> >     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true
> >     -Djava.security.manager=worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.BootstrapSecurityManager
> >     -Dorg.gradle.native=false -noverify -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -ea -cp /home/circleci/.gradle/caches/4.10.1/workerMain/gradle-worker.jar
> >     worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain 'Gradle
> >     Test Executor 2' Successfully started process 'Gradle Test Executor 2'
> >
> > com.mindvalley.mva.loginmodule.LoginActivityTest > isSkipLoginVisible
> >     STANDARD_OUT
> >         [Robolectric] com.mindvalley.mva.loginmodule.LoginActivityTest.isSkipLoginVisible:
> >     sdk=28; resources=binary
> >         Called loadFromPath(/system/framework/framework-res.apk, true); mode=binary sdk=28
> >
> > com.mindvalley.mva.loginmodule.LoginActivityTest > isSkipLoginVisible
> >     SKIPPED
> >
> > > Task :app:testInternalReleaseUnitTest FAILED :app:testInternalReleaseUnitTest (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread
> > >       2,5,main]) completed. Took 3.413 secs.
> >
> > FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> >
> > - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:testInternalReleaseUnitTest'.
> >
> >   > Process 'Gradle Test Executor 2' finished with non-zero exit value 137   This problem might be caused by incorrect test process
> >   >       configuration.   Please refer to the test execution section in the
> >   >       user guide at
> >   >       https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.1/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:test_execution
> > - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get
> >       full insights.
> > - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

My LoginTestActivity

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(manifest = Config.NONE, application = MockApplication.class)
public class LoginActivityTest {

    private LoginActivity activity;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(LoginActivity.class).create().resume().get();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldNotBeNull() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(activity);
    }

    /**
     * check by default visibility. It should be not visible
     * Once we change variable in Login module it should be Visible
     */
    @Test
    public void isSkipLoginVisible() {
        TextView skipLogin = activity.findViewById(com.mindvalley.loginmodule.R.id.skip_login);
        LoginModule.getInstance().setSkipLogin(false);
        activity.setSkipLoginVisibility();
        Assert.assertTrue(skipLogin.getVisibility() == View.GONE);
        LoginModule.getInstance().setSkipLogin(true);
        activity.setSkipLoginVisibility();
        Assert.assertTrue( skipLogin.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Test
    public void enableActionButtonTest() {
        CustomFeedbackText loginButton = activity.findViewById(com.mindvalley.loginmodule.R.id.login_btn_login);
        String email = "";
        String password = "";
        activity.enableActionButton(email, password);
        Assert.assertTrue(!loginButton.isEnabled());
        email = "harsh@mindvalley.com";
        password = "123";
        activity.enableActionButton(email, password);
        Assert.assertTrue(loginButton.isEnabled());
    }

    @Test
    public void skipLoginClicked() {
        TextView skipLogin = activity.findViewById(com.mindvalley.loginmodule.R.id.skip_login);
        Assert.assertTrue(!PreferenceManager.getBoolean(LoginModule.SKIP_LOGIN, false));
        skipLogin.performClick();
        Assert.assertTrue(PreferenceManager.getBoolean(LoginModule.SKIP_LOGIN, false));
    }

    @Test
    public void sanitizeLogin() {
        String email = "";
        String password = "";
        Assert.assertTrue(!activity.sanitizeLogin(email, password));
        email = "harsh";
        password = "";
        Assert.assertTrue(!activity.sanitizeLogin(email, password));
        email = "harsh@mindvalley";
        password = "";
        Assert.assertTrue(!activity.sanitizeLogin(email, password));
        email = "harsh@mindvalley.com";
        password = "";
        Assert.assertTrue(!activity.sanitizeLogin(email, password));
        email = "harsh@mindvalley.com";
        password = "test";
        Assert.assertTrue(!activity.sanitizeLogin(email, password));
        email = "harsh@mindvalley.com";
        password = "test123";
        Assert.assertTrue(activity.sanitizeLogin(email, password));
    }

    @Test
    public void loginClicked() {
        CustomFeedbackText loginButton = activity.findViewById(com.mindvalley.loginmodule.R.id.login_btn_login);
        EditText emailEditText = activity.findViewById(com.mindvalley.loginmodule.R.id.login_edittext_email);
        EditText passwordEditText = activity.findViewById(com.mindvalley.loginmodule.R.id.login_edittext_password);
        emailEditText.setText("harsh@mindvalley.com");
        passwordEditText.setText("test123");
        loginButton.performClick();
        Assert.assertTrue(Util_Auth0.getInstance().getAndroidClient() != null);
        // test update prefs method
        activity.updatePrefs();
        Assert.assertTrue(!PreferenceManager.getBoolean(LoginModule.SKIP_LOGIN, false));
        Assert.assertTrue(PreferenceManager.getBoolean(LoginModule.SIGNED_IN, false));
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        activity = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer here

https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/4591#event-2116260870

Here is the link to stackoverflow answer [Why are my Gradle builds dying with exit-code 137?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38967991/why-are-my-gradle-builds-dying-with-exit-code-137)

Thanks Christian Williams